# Jquery: Stop effect occuring on submenu item when primary menu is hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a nested sub menu within a primary menu. When the user hovers over a primary menu item an image fades in and fades out on hover out. The same is meant to happen with the sub menu.

My issue is the image from the primary menu item does not fade out when I hover over its nested sub menu. I have tried using `.not()` (eg: `.not('ul li')` ) but to no effect.

I have also tried targeting the the parent item directly when the the sub menu item is hovered over, also to no effect. (eg: `$(this).parent().parent().find("a").html();` )

Does anyone know a way to modify my script so that hovering over the first menu item does not effect the 2nd nested item?

```
//FADE SUB MENU IMAGES    
$("#menu > ul > li > ul > li").hover(
      function () {
        var linktext = $(this).find("a").html(); 
        $('img[alt="' + linktext + '"]').stop().fadeIn('100');
         //FADEOUT PRIMARY MENU ITEM IMAGE
         var linktexttop = $(this).parent().parent().find("a").html();
        $('img[alt="' + linktexttop + '"]').stop().fadeIn('100');
      },
      function () {
        var linktext = $(this).find("a").html();
        $('img[alt="' + linktext + '"]').fadeOut('100');
      }
    );
```

EDIT: Added fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/veW7B/3/

In the fiddle - when the sub menu is hovered over I only want the blue square to show, not both

Comment: Mind creating a fiddle to mess with, might help this along :)

Comment: @tymeJV sure - check back in five

Comment: @tymeJV added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/veW7B/3/ notice how when you hover over the sub menu items both coloured squares show. I want only the blue square to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) and [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to select which 'li' has a child and which one does not.

Use `$('li').has('ul').hover()` for the Primary li, and use `$("li:not(:has(ul))").hover()` for the sub-menu

I have updated your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/veW7B/5/